# How to connect to kafka installed using confluent helm chart

Tags: go, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have a kubernetes cluster hosted on azure cloud. I had installed kafka resources using below helm chart https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka. This helm chart successfully deployed zoopkeeper pods and broker pods etc. Now I want to write a golang based application which connects with any of the kafka broker installed on my kubernetes cluster and creates a new producer and publishes messages. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your Go code so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following string in bootstrap.servers to communicate with the brokers `<helm-release-name>-cp-kafka-headless.<namespace>:9092` or bootstrap service which is created as part of confluent helm chart `<helm-release-name>-cp-kafka`. When you hit this service, it will randomly got to any of the brokers for the first time and get all the metadata information which is synced through zookeeper.

The subsequent requests will be made to individual brokers based on information found in metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You would deploy your Golang code in a container, in k8s, then set `bootstrap.servers` to the Kafka Deployment's Service name, ideally via an environment variable